# C++17 Compiler is not visible/detected in Visual Studio Code 2022 and codeblock

Tags: c++, c++17

Have recently installed C++ related packages in my laptop.
Installed
gcc & g++ compiler with msys64 pacman tool. Both the compilers are at v13.x
When I run my test program from visual studio code, it gives c++17 is available.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello C++\n";
    if (__cplusplus == 201703L) std::cout << "C++17\n";  
    else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) std::cout << "C++14\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::cout << "C++11\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::cout << "C++98\n";
    else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";
```

}

When I run same program in Visual Studio 2022 Community and codeblock, gives c++98 version. I tried changing the C++ Language selections but still getting same output.

Could someone help me with this?
[image]

Tried changing Compiler and language settings in both the tools, still getting same result

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2022 is using the Microsoft compiler (`cl.exe`), not g++.

Comment: What is the question? How to fix `__cplusplus` in Visual Studio. Are you ok with C++17 being reported by G++?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft didn't dare to change the macro after being at C++98 for 20 years! So they added a special option to enable an updated value:

/Zc:__cplusplus

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-170

Comment: And if you don't want your code to rely on compiler flags, read the proper value from the `_MSVC_LANG` macro if its defined.